# remove from a list of tuples according to the second part of the tuple in python

Tags: python

`contacts.remove((name,ip))`

I have the ip and it's unique. I want to remove this tuple from contacts according to the ip and no need to name.

I just tried this `contacts.remove((pass,ip))`, but I encountered an error.

Comment: `pass` is a statement, therefore it can't be used in an expression this way. And `None` is an actual value, so it also won't work.

Answer (score 11):

```
contacts = [(name, ip) for name, ip in contacts if ip != removable_ip]
```

or

```
for x in xrange(len(contacts) - 1, -1, -1):
    if contacts[x][1] == removable_ip:
        del contacts[x]
        break # removable_ip is allegedly unique
```

The first method rebinds `contacts` to a newly-created list that excludes the desired entry. The second method updates the original list; it goes backwards to avoid being tripped up by the `del` statement moving the rug under its feet.

Answer (score 4):

Since the `ip` to remove is unique, you don't need all the usual precautions about modifying a container you're iterating on -- thus, the simplest approach becomes:

```
for i, (name, anip) in enumerate(contacts):
  if anip == ip:
    del contacts[i]
    break
```

Answer (score 1):

This answers my not created question. Thanks for the explanation, but let me summarize and generalize the answers for multiple deletion and Python 3.

```
list = [('ADC', 3),
        ('UART', 1),
        ('RemoveMePlease', 42),
        ('PWM', 2),
        ('MeTooPlease', 6)]

list1 = [(d, q)
         for d, q in list
         if d not in {'RemoveMePlease', 'MeTooPlease'}]

print(list1)

for i, (d, q) in enumerate(list):
    if d in {'RemoveMePlease', 'MeTooPlease'}:
        del(list[i])

print(list)
```

[The corresponding help topic](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)